# How to traverse a tree/array based on a api call -Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

Is there a way to traverse a tree using DFS, where the tree is not predefined with all its children but based on a server response. example, lets say I have a tree:

tree = ['a','b','c'];
In the above case I have no idea wether these nodes have any children or not, I get to know when I make a call to the server.
so now I take the first node of the tree , i.e 'a' and pass it to the url:

`"https://test.com/'a'` and get a response with children of node 'a'.

o/p: 'a'= ['1','2','3'];

and then I take the first node of 'a' i.e: '1', (so something like, tree['a']['1'])
and pass it to the same url, like `"https://test.com/'1'` and get response with all the children of node '1'.
What I'm trying to say is I do not have an idea how many children does a node have unless I call for an api. Hence my code here goes into some infinite loop.also it does not do a DFS, but does a BFS.

```
function getNode(arr) {
    fetch("https://test.com/'a'", function(data){
        if (Array.isArray(data)) {
            data.forEach(function(node,i){
                var promises = resolve(self.getNode(arr[i]));
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Any clue how this kind of approach works?
Thanks

Comment: Probably need more information about the API? Are you sure you're not stuck in a loop?
  **Example:** `a -> 1 -> ... -> a -> 1 -> ...`?

Comment: api returns: ```{id:1, data:["abc","dad","test"]}``` and then I pass "abc" to url, which return other set of object with its children. the api at one point does not return any data, i.e it returns only ```{id:12}```, thats when its considered to reach the end.

Comment: I tried passing the first child of every node manually and I do get towards the end of the search, but with the code above, it takes the BFS approach and runs into session timeout since the tree is pretty deep

Comment: One possible way if you can get length of nodes and just make x number of calls at a time and save index and recursively call with delay to prevent making all calls at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get data from API, so the main problem is asynchronous data handle. Using [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) will make it easier.

Consider a tree

```
a b c
|
1------------2
|            |
11,12,13     21,22,23
```

Use `async/await`

```
/**
 * simulate fetch which returns a promise
 */
async function fetch(url) {
  const node = url.replace('https://test.com/', '');
  switch (node) {
    case 'a':
      return [1, 2];
    case '1':
      return [11, 12, 13];
    case '2':
      return [21, 22, 23];
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

/**
 * getNode will also return a promise
 */
async function getNode(node) {
  console.log('node:', node);

  const data = await fetch(`https://test.com/${node}`);
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      await getNode(data[i]);
    }
  }
}

getNode('a');
```

Output

```
node: a
node: 1
node: 11
node: 12
node: 13
node: 2
node: 21
node: 22
node: 23
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an asynchronous recursive function to fill the tree in. Your function already have most of the parts required. Two missing parts arethe the parent node for each recursion and url each recursion should fetch data from.

Assuming an imaginary `addNode(aParent, aNode)` function which adds a node to the tree:

```
function getNode(parentNode, url) {

   //Get remote data from this url
   fetch(url, function(data){

       if (Array.isArray(data)) {

                //Go through each node it returns
                data.forEach(function(childNode){

                    //Add to the specified parent  
                    addNode(parentNode, childNode);

                    //Construct the new url and 
                    //call the same function with each received child as a parent
                    getNode(url + '/' + childNode, childNode);
                })

            }
      });
}
```

When invoked with the root node and the base url, the function will start traversing the API and build the tree as the responses are received.

*You can have an additional depth parameter and control how deep each recursion go. This might be useful if you want to load the tree as the user clicks on each node.*

Comment: sorry I missed this part in API but the api does return with the depth. i.e: ```{id:1, data:['''], depth: 0}``` and when I make a call with the first child of the parent, the ```depth``` level changes to 2 and so on, and roughly by depth 9 or 10 it reached the end.